# SQL Top 1 in XML Path ('')

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following code:

```
    select(

    select m.Code + '   ' + cast(m.Completed as varchar(max)) + '   '+ cast(ol.Billed as varchar(max)) + '  ' + cast(m.Delete as varchar (max)) 
    from matterdetails as m
    full join officeledger as ol on ol.id=m.id
    order by ol.Billed desc 

    for xml path(''))
```

returns the results

```
    Code       Completed     Billed        Deleted
    --------   -----------   -----------   -----------
    HK168/03   Mar 30 2012   Aug 17 2011   Mar 30 2012
    HK168/03   Mar 30 2012   Feb 24 2011   Mar 30 2012
    HK168/03   Mar 30 2012   Dec 23 2010   Mar 30 2012
    FT080/03   Apr  4 2012   Mar 29 2012   Apr  4 2012
    FT080/03   Apr  4 2012   Feb  9 2012   Apr  4 2012
    FT080/03   Apr  4 2012   Oct 20 2011   Apr  4 2012

    etc.
```

whereas i require the results

```
    Code       Completed     Billed        Deleted
    --------   -----------   -----------   -----------
    HK168/03   Mar 30 2012   Aug 17 2011   Mar 30 2012
    FT080/03   Apr  4 2012   Mar 29 2012   Apr  4 2012

    etc.
```

I know that i have to insert a `select top 1` somewhere to limit the `ol.Billed` results, but i am unsure where. Any advice would be great.

Comment: there are so many [sql server top 1 per group](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+top+1+per+group) questions on SO, just pick one closest to your liking

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Get Top 1 of Each Group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/sql-server-get-top-1-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: It will join with the max Billed Date for each Id

```
   select(
    select m.Code + '   ' + cast(m.Completed as varchar(max)) + '   '+ cast(ol.Billed as varchar(max)) + '  ' + cast(m.Delete as varchar (max)) 
    matterdetails as m
    full join (select id, Max(billed) as 'Billed' from officeledger) as ol on ol.id=m.id
        order by ol.Billed desc 
for xml path(''))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace:

```
full join officeledger as ol on ol.id=m.id
```

with:

```
full join (select id,MIN(Billed) as Billed from officeledger group by id) as ol = ol.id = m.id
```

There should also be a way to do this with `ROW_NUMBER()`, but I won't write it unless you need it.